# Running and getting sequentially progress from Q Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have this code, i want that this two Promise runs sequentially and result should be like this:

```
a progress: 20
a progress: 40
a progress: 60
a progress: 80
a progress: 100
a resolve: a

b progress: 20
b progress: 40
b progress: 60
b progress: 80
b progress: 100
b resolve: b
```

but i get this:

```
a progress: 20
b progress: undefined
a progress: 40
b progress: undefined
a progress: 60
b progress: undefined
a progress: 80
b progress: undefined
a progress: 100
a resolve: a
b progress: undefined
b progress: 20
b progress: 40
b progress: 60
b progress: 80
b progress: 100
b resolve: b
```

this is my entire code:

```
var a =  function(){
        return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify){
            var percentage = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                percentage += 20;
                notify(percentage);
                if (percentage === 100) {
                    resolve("a");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    };

    var b =  function(){
        return q.Promise(function(resolve, reject, notify){
            var percentage = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                percentage += 20;
                notify(percentage);
                if (percentage === 100) {
                    resolve("b");
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    };


    a().then(function(res) {
            console.log('a resolve: '+res);
            return b();
        },
        errorHandler,
        function(progress){
            console.log('a progress: '+progress);
        })

        //call b()
        .then(function(res){
            console.log('b resolve: '+res);
        },
        errorHandler,
        function(progress){
            console.log('b progress: '+progress);
        });

    function errorHandler(err) {
        console.log('Error Handler:', err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Q's chaining](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#chaining).

```
a()
.then(
    function(res) {
        b().then(function(resb) {
            console.log('b resolve: '+resb);
        },
        errorHandler,
        function(progress){
            console.log('b progress: '+progress);
        });
    },
    errorHandler,
    function(progress){
        console.log('a progress: '+progress);
    });
```

Using `fin` works too:

```
a()
.then(
    function(res) {
        console.log('a resolve: '+res);
    },
    errorHandler,
    function(progress){
        console.log('a progress: '+progress);
    })
.fin(function() {
    b().then(function(res) {
        console.log('b resolve: '+res);
    },
    errorHandler,
    function(progress){
        console.log('b progress: '+progress);
    });
});
```

Let's look at the original code's flow:

```
a().then(function(res) {
        console.log('a resolve: '+res);
        return b(); // (0) here we only create promise for 'b'
    },
    errorHandler,
    function(progress){
        console.log('a progress: '+progress); // (1) here Q calls progress's callback
    })

    //call b()
    .then(function(res){
        console.log('b resolve: '+res); // (2) it's called in the end
    },
    errorHandler,
    function(progress){
        console.log('b progress: '+progress);  // (1) and here Q calls progress's callback
    });
```

'b progress: undefined' is because there is exactly no progress, but callback is called. Progress callbacks are called while promises aren't fullfilled. Promise get fullfilled when you return something or call 'resolve'.

Comment: The way i use is not chaining? according to the documentation it is! you just because of return b() , nested all code inside a's then section. but why? i dont use nesting . its like  callback pyramid

Comment: document says "You can chain promises either inside or outside handlers". i want to use outside to have a flat code. it says these two is equivalent but why this is not in action? your code is inside handler , my code is outside but your's work, not mine

Comment: I'm thinking about explaination.

Comment: actually my code is work for resolve section, i mean resolving's gets sequential but only progress section runs like parallel

Comment: @Fcoder: Progress notification is deprecated exactly because it does not follow these semantics. If you chain, the events will bubble through all handlers, so you need to nest if you want to treat them separately.